# How to show convergence in probability by just using the definition?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a series of random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ where

$$ f(X_n) =
  \begin{cases}
    1/n       & \quad \text{if} \  X_n = 1 \\
    1-1/n    & \quad \text{if} \ X_n = 0 \\
    0  & \quad \text{otherwise}\\
  \end{cases}
$$

I am trying to show that $X_n \to 0$ in probability. I have trying to use the definition of convergence in probability but do not know how to bound the $\epsilon$'s. Is it possible to directly use the definition in this case? The definition of convergence in probability I am working with is:

$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left(|X_n - X| > \epsilon\right)=0$. Thanks!

Comment: where does $f$ come in?

Comment: @YonatanN: $f(X_n)$  is presumably the probability mass function for $X_n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider an $1>\epsilon>0$. For all $n$, $|X_n-0|=0$ with probability $1-1/n$, and $|X_n-0|=1$ with probability $1/n$. So 
$$Pr(|X_n-0|>\epsilon)=\frac{1}{n}$$
since $|X_n-0|>\epsilon$ only when $X_n=1$. $1/n$ converges to 0 as $n \to \infty$.

If $\epsilon \geq 1$, then $Pr(|X_n-0|>\epsilon)=0$ for all $n$.